# Programmatically select next/previous option in select 2, with sorter applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 that uses the `sorter` option to sort options alphabetically, and a button that should select the next option after the currently selected option.  All of this works as desired except the button does not select the next (alphabetical) choice in the select2, which is what I would like; instead it selects the next `<option>` element in the underlying `<select>` that drives the select2.  These `<option>`'s are not sorted alphabetically. Obviously I could manipulate the DOM to sort them alphabetically, but that sort of defeats the purpose of leveraging the `sorter` option.  Is there any way to identify the option that comes after the currently selected one, in the sorted list?

HTML

```
<select id="employeeSelect">
  <option value="abc">Diane Smith</option>
  <option value="xyz">Tim Carter</option>
  <option value="dmv">Keith Appleton</option>
  <option value="r2d2">Carla Peters</option>
</select>
<button id="nextEmployee">Next</button>
```

JS

```
$('#employeeSelect').select2({
  placeholder: '-- select an employee --',
  sorter: data => data.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text)),
})

$('#nextEmployee').on('click', function(){
  $("#employeeSelect > option:selected")
    .prop("selected", false)
    .next()
    .prop("selected", true);
  $('#employeeSelect').trigger('change');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any documentation on this, but from inspecting the select2 element's data properties, it appears that the sorted list is not held in the select2's internal data in any way (I think it is generated on the fly when the dropdown is clicked); therefore, this is probably not possible other than by sorting the `<option>` tags.

So my current solution looks like this:

```
$('#nextEmployee').on('click', function(){
    const isBefore = function (a, b)
    {
      return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase()) < 0
    }
    const selectedOption = $("#employeeSelect > option:selected")
    const nextOption = $('#employeeSelect').find('option').toArray()
      .reduce(function (acc, thisOption)
      {
        if (isBefore(selectedOption, thisOption)
          && (!acc || isBefore(thisOption, acc)))
        {
          return thisOption
        } else
        {
          return acc
        }
      }, null)

    if (nextOption)
    {
      selectedOption.prop("selected", false)
      $(nextOption).prop("selected", true);
      $('#employeeSelect').trigger('change');
    }
  }
```